# How to get Authorization header from response in React with CORS, Spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

In my project when logging a user in a jwt token gets returned in the response header but I cannot access this header, can anybody tell me how ?

this is my login function

```
   const username = useRef();
     const password = useRef();
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     function loginHandler() {
               axios.post("/auth/login", {
                    username: username.current.value,
                    password: password.current.value
               })
               .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.headers)
                    window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.headers.get("Authorization"))
                    navigate("/shoes/mens")
               });
     }
```

[here is the Authorization header of my response so you can see that it does indeed return a jwt token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcHfD.png)

Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http = http.csrf().disable().cors().and();

    http = http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and();

    http = http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, ex) -> {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());
            }).and();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/storage/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

This used to work for me but now when enabline cors.and() in backend it stopped working for me. thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: `Authorization` is typically used as a request header. Why is there a header of that name in the response?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out how to fix it after hours of searching, for someone with the same problem

create a configuration file that implements WebMvcconfigurer
and overide the addCorsMappings method then in the exposed headers u put the headers u want to expose eg Authorization `

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization");
    }
}
```